# How to work with Primary Userstore in wso2esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using 4.8.1.
I wish to authenticate against of Carbon Users-tore with plain text password.
If we use Username-tokens Signature its easy to do but my client having some other Header like

```
 <soapenv:Header>
      <mw:authentication soapenv:soa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/soa/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:mw="http://soa.dev.com/mwoxy">
         <mw:user>admin</mw:user>
         <mw:password>admin</mw:password>
      </mw:authentication>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

So I wish to authenticate this inside proxy so that i wrote a proxy like  this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="authent" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
        <target>
            <inSequence>
                <property name="username" expression="//mw:authentication/mw:user/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="password" expression="//mw:authentication/mw:password/text() type="STRING"/>
                <dblookup>
                    <connection>
                        <pool>
                            <dsName>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dsName>
                        </pool>
                    </connection>
                    <statement>
                        <sql>select  UM_USER_NAME  from UM_USER where UM_USER_NAME=? and UM_USER_PASSWORD= ?</sql>
                        <parameter expression="get-property('username')" type="VARCHAR"/>
                        <parameter expression="get-property('password')" type="VARCHAR"/>
                        <result name="IsUserExisted" column="UM_USER_NAME"/>
                    </statement>
                </dblookup>
                <log level="full">
                    <property name="IsUserExisted" expression="get-property('IsUserExisted')"/>
                </log>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence/>
        </target>
        <description/>
    </proxy>
```

So i wish authenticate against of Primary UserStore for that I used this query

**select  UM_USER_NAME  from UM_USER where UM_USER_NAME=? and UM_USER_PASSWORD= ?**
   and changes done in user-mgt.xml file  but its not working how would i do beacuse there is just 3 user and password's is there.
   the configuration is like this

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager</Property>
        <Property name="ReadOnly">false</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="IsEmailUserName">false</Property>
            <Property name="DomainCalculation">default</Property>
     <!-- <Property name="PasswordDigest">SHA-256</Property>-->
            <Property name="StoreSaltedPassword">true</Property>
            <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameUniqueAcrossTenants">false</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[^~!#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;,\'\"]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">^[^~!#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;,\'\"]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="SharedGroupEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
        </UserStoreManager>
```

Its not working how would i achive this

Thnks in advance

Comment: its giving like this [2014-09-05 11:45:40,700]  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/authent.authentHttpSoap12Endpoint, WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uu
id:879d9d4f-8d25-45e0-9ffc-636ba0044ec7, Direction: request, IsUserExisted = null, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soa
penv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: I am getting this message while i am trying to lo-gin using console         [2014-09-05 12:10:12,560]  WARN - CarbonAuthenticationUtil Failed Administrator
login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2014-09-05 12:10:12,547+0530]

Answer (score 0):

you are using a wrong approach. I believe you are trying to secure your proxy service using username and password. So basically you can secure your proxy from applying a username and password secure policy as shown in [1].

[1]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Applying+Security+Policies

Comment: But i am not getting as per Username-Token format .I am getting different header how would i overcome this

Comment: Instead of writing new policy i want to use just validate with query